# What is the behaviour of an order-only prerequisite where the prerequisite is a phony target?

Tags: makefile

I am wondering if the order-only prerequisite loses its order-only precedence if it is a phony target.  Consider the following:

```
%.make: unpack_chroot
    schroot $(CHROOT) make $*

%.copy: | unpack_chroot
    rsync -a input/$*/ $(CHROOT)/input/$*/

unpack_chroot: input/chroot.tar.gz
    mkdir -p $(CHROOT)
    tar -C $(CHROOT) -zxf $<

.PHONY: unpack_chroot
```

All %.make and %.copy targets are `.PHONY`.  Some of these targets depend on files being copied into the chroot, others do not.  Those that do are defined with explicit dependencies:

```
a.make: a.copy
c.make: c.copy
```

However, if `unpack_chroot` is not an order-only prerequisite and was unpacked as part of the processing of prerequisites for another make target **not** in the same make process, `unpack_chroot` will be considered up-to-date when %.copy runs and will not remake %.copy; at least that is what I have seen.  Currently, `unpack_chroot` is not phony and gets created.  I want to make it phony, but want to clarify the behaviour.

Comment: You write: _if `unpack_chroot` is not an order-only prerequisite and was unpacked as part of the processing of prerequisites for another make target [... make] will not remake `%.copy`_.  This is certainly not true.  If a normal prerequisite is rebuilt then all targets that depend on it will be rebuilt.  However, depending on virtual targets like this is typically not a good idea, since every new invocation of make will re-run the target.  Also declaring that rule `.PHONY` will force all targets that depend on it normally to always rebuild.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  Have updated the question.  If the prerequisite was built by another make process.  However, in saying that, I created a small stand-alone test to examine the debug output from make.  In this case, make is doing the right thing and the order-only prerequisite is not required.  I do not know why it is required in the actual makefile, since the dependency processing should be the same.  I will need to generate the debug for the live build and see what it is actually doing that requires the order-only prerequisite.

Comment: I'm going to bin this question, since I don't think it's relevant to what I _thought_ was going on.

Comment: I think it does make sense. The order-only phony prerequisite is something that probably wasn't even predicted by creators of Make. And this is interesting case for me as I'm developing my own Make-like (Silvercat on gitlab) tool and can use this case for something useful. Normally this is "fresh", when there's a file. So if it's a phony the target, it *might* be updated only if, by updating other prerequisites, the target is already considered stale. I'm *confabulating* of course, but such a feature would be useful.

Answer (score -3):

According to this email ( http://kolpackov.net/pipermail/notes/2004-January/000001.html ) it seems that the only difference between normal and order only prerequisites is that the latter will not be included in automatic make variables such as $^.

From some tests I ran it seems that this is the only difference. In all other respects they are treated the same as normal prerequisites.

Comment: No, order-only prerequisites will not cause a target to be rebuilt if the target is older than the order-only prerequisite.